# Android Screen Recorder - NDK

Tags: android, screen, record

I want to programmatically capture the screen video using Android NDK. I have found the code in google source, which does exactly what I am looking for (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/cmds/screenrecord/screenrecord.cpp). But I am stuck on how to use the code.

1. Does header files included in the code are shipped as part of NDK? If yes, then which are the libraries I have to add my android.mk file?
2. Do I need download source code of all the relevant library and add to my project and compile them along with my code?

Thanks

Comment: "I have found the code in google source, which does exactly what I am looking for" -- that is the code for a development tool, not for an Android app. Unless your app is running with superuser privileges, I doubt that code can run, even if you can get it building.

Comment: Thanks for that, otherwise I would have spent unnecessary time on it.

Comment: MediaProjection library in android 5.0 onwards have a API to capture screen recording, but it prompt the user whether to allow screen capture. I don't want to show any popup to user. Is there any way to record a screen without prompt the user?

Comment: "Is there any way to record a screen without prompt the user?" -- fortunately, no, except via development tools or on rooted devices, for obvious privacy and security reasons.